# Rails i18n passing a URL parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm using i18n with Rails succesfully but when I pass a parameter in the url i18n stops working and seems to fallback to English. My form labels are switched back to English instead of Dutch. How can I prevent this from happening?

Relevant lines:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
config.i18n.locale = :nl
```

Example URL:

```
#/users?param1=abc

localized do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: Could you provide an example URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're supplying the locale in the URL (I can not make that up out of the information you supplied) then you can make sure it always gets passed to URL helper by overriding the default URL options with a snippet like this in your application controller:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

Via http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Answer (score 0):

Use as in rails guide:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :books
end
```

Set locale:

```
before_filter :set_current_locale

private
def set_current_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end
```